# Hot to get user folder with graalvm native using "user.dir" on Linux

Tags: java, linux, native, graalvm

So i am having a problem to get user "user.dir" file location. when I compile while not in native mode I get the normal path that I can also point to in the file manager but when I build a native image all I get is "root" as user folder, is there another way to correct this because I can even call root as a folder path to act on the file system.

```java
 public static void printAllGuaranteedProperties() {
      
       printAProperty ("user.dir", "User's current working directory");
    }
    public static void printAProperty (String propName, String desc) {
       System.out.println ("Value for '" + desc + "' is '" + System.getProperty(propName) + "'.");
    }
```

the sample code above , just try to run this you will the results difference , I was using jdk 17 community edition for graalvm . make sure you build and image and test this as well .

Comment: Your sample code works for me, prints current directory. I'm on Linux using
`GraalVM 22.2.0 Java 17 CE (Java Version 17.0.4+8-jvmci-22.2-b06)`

Comment: [This comment](https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/577#issuecomment-408845812) might be useful

Comment: I see there is abit of confusion here , I am not looking to get the current directory or folder , but I need to get the user home folder for example in linux "/home/userfolder/" , so far System.getProperty("user.dir")    is returning current folder when when you build a native image app .

Comment: This behavior is correct. For user's home directory, try `user.home` property

Comment: yes I see now , how does on get the home folder then ? so far its returning "root" ?

Comment: Are you running native image as root user? `/root` is root user's home directory

Comment: yes i am running as root. I think I get it in away so by the fact of me running the image as admin , my default home folder reference is now root?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a small confusion here. user.dir is for working directory and .home is for home folder.
"**user.dir**"  User working directory

"**user.home**"     User home directory

check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html has more system properties

I used your code and called this rest service and print the output you can see the result below
[image: quarkus exe run with root]